# table Undefined control sequence

Tags: tables, errors

i am getting error when i am running code of table. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
161 Undefined control sequence. l.161 \multirow
               {4}{*}{active interaction} & 1-2 {[}Hz{]} & The maximum bandw...
```

---

**List of packages which I am using for overall report writting**

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}\normalsize 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp} 

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{theorem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\usepackage{commath} 
\usepackage{bm} 

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelblau}{rgb}{0,0,0.5} 
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}

\numberwithin{figure}{section} 

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} %
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead[]{\pagemark} 
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{1 cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1 cm}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%extra added for table
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\usepackage{listings} 

\usepackage{bibgerm} 
\usepackage{leftidx}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode} 

\numberwithin{table}{section} 

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For table and figure list naming:

\newpage 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}

\listoffigures

\newpage 
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

Comment: Start from your comment suggestion: `% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:`

Comment: Did you add the multirow package to your preamble? In the code fragment you included, it is commented out.

Comment: I have made table on https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#. i just posted the code to my report and gort error

Comment: We need to see complete compilable but small document with your table. Otherwise we can only guess what cause your error.

Comment: please always post complete documents that show the problem, and also use a code block for error messages, you used a quote but that loses line breaks and the line breaks are essential, the one in your error tells you that it is `\multirow` that is not defined (as presumably  you had not followed the instructions in the comments to define it)

Comment: that table generator comes up here from time to time but why use it? It makes massively over-complicated tex (you could remove _all_ those `\multicolum{{1}{...` commands) It would be simpler to write the tex code directly.

Comment: actually i am new on latex and hence i used online coding. could you please help me to make table as i added in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope --could not find any error--had to reduce one column to 8cm to avoid spill over

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
U                                                          & Frequee                             & Descn                                         \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{interaction}}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1-2 {[}Hz{]}}   & \multicolumn{1}{p{8cm}|}{The maximum bandwidth with which the human finger can react to unexpected force/ position signals}                      \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5-10 {[}Hz{]}}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{vvvv}                      \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{8-10 {[}Hz{]}}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{vvvv}                       \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{8-12 {[}Hz{]}}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{vvces}                       \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{section}                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{12-16 {[}Hz{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{The  cannot correct ps}      \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{interaction}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{20-30 {[}Hz{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{The which the human finger demans taperception} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{320 {[}Hz{]}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{The yond which the human fingers cannot discrimins}                         \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5-10 {[}kHz{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{The human finger needs to sense vibratitive tasks}                  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like the following?

[image]

Note that I've deliberately dropped all vertical lines and almost all horizontal lines, in order to give the table a more open and inviting look. After all, what purpose is served if the table is so uninviting that none of your readers will spend more than two seconds glancing at it? Input-wise, I've also replaced all instances of `{[}Hz{]}}` with `Hz`, and I've switched from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment. A side effect of these simplifications is that the multitude of utterly pointless `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}` directives can be deleted, making the input much easier to take in -- and check for any errors of *content*.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llL @{}}
\toprule
U  & Frequee & Descn \\ 
\midrule
interaction & 1--2 Hz & The maximum bandwidth with which the human finger can react to unexpected force\slash position signals \\
            & 5--10 Hz & vvvv  \\
            & 8--10 Hz & vvvv  \\
            & 8--12 Hz & vvces \\ 
\addlinespace
section     & 12--16 Hz & The cannot correct ps \\ 
\addlinespace
interaction & 20--30 Hz & The which the human finger demans taperception \\
            & 320 Hz    & The yond which the human fingers cannot discrimins \\ 
            & 5--10 kHz & The human finger needs to sense vibratitive tasks \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for better than mine formatting of table -;

Comment: LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 152.


! LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.153 \begin{tabularx}
                      {\textwidth}{@{} llL @{}}
?

Comment: i dont know why i am getting error

Comment: \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
%\usepackage{booktabs}

Comment: when i am running your independently from my report. its workin. when i am installing packages in my main installation file and running my report file. it dont work. getting error  ! LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.259 \begin{tabularx}
                      {\textwidth}{@{} llL @{}}
?

Comment: @maths, please, please again. edit your question and extend your code fragment to complete but small document, which we can test as it is and in which we can see, which document class and other package you use. Without it saying that you obtain errors only tell, that your document is very different from those, which we used in our MWE.

Comment: @maths - The error message "LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined." will will most definitely arise if you don't load the `tabularx` package.

Comment: Hi @Zarko  i added my file packages which i am using in question.

Answer (score 5):

Your table code does not reproduce showed error. However, I would redesign your table to something like this:

[image]

IN your table code i would remove all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` which is only clutter in code. Also I would remove vertical lines (combination of the rules from `booktabs` package and vertical lines gives ugly result). Text in last columns sre to long that table can be fit in text area. A solution is to use column type which break test into more lines. For this I suggest to use `tabularx` and `X` column type. For writing units is intended excellent package `siunitx` which support their writing according to SI standard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{} }
    \toprule
U   & Frequee   & Descn                     \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{8}{*}{interaction}    
    &   \SIrange{1}{2}{\hertz}
        &   The maximum bandwidth with which the human finger can react to unexpected force/position signals              \\ 
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{5}{10}{\hertz}   &   vvvv    \\ 
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{8}{10}{\hertz}   &   vvvv    \\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{8}{10}{\hertz}   &  vvces    \\ 
    \midrule
section
    & \SIrange{12}{16}{\hertz}  &   The  cannot correct ps  \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{interaction} 
    & \SIrange{12}{30}{\hertz}  &  The which the human finger demans taperception \\ %    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SI{320}{\hertz}          &  The yond which the human fingers cannot discrimins\\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{5}{10}{\hertz}   &  The human finger needs to sense vibratitive tasks\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
I test my solution with your document preamble. It gives warnings (not error) that used package `scrpage2` should be replaced with `scrlayer-scrpage`. Doing this and moving the `hyperref` package to the end of preamble and consider, that in your document you change `\baselinestretch`, the new version of mine MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}\normalsize

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{theorem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelblau}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} % THIS PACKAGE IS OBSOLETE
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       % REPLACEMENT FOR THE OBSOLETE "scrpage2" PACKAGE
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{1 cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1 cm}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%extra added for table
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage{leftidx}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}

\numberwithin{table}{section}

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt} % due to 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
%%%%    \makegapedcells % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{} }
    \toprule
U   & Frequee   & Descn                     \\
    \midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{interaction}
    &   \SIrange{1}{2}{\hertz}
        &   The maximum bandwidth with which the human finger can react to unexpected force/position signals              \\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{5}{10}{\hertz}   &   vvvv    \\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{8}{10}{\hertz}   &   vvvv    \\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{8}{10}{\hertz}   &  vvces    \\
    \midrule
section
    & \SIrange{12}{16}{\hertz}  &   The  cannot correct ps  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{interaction}
    & \SIrange{12}{30}{\hertz}  &  The which the human finger demans taperception \\ %    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SI{320}{\hertz}          &  The bond which the human fingers cannot discrimins\\
%    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & \SIrange{5}{10}{\hertz}   &  The human finger needs to sense vibratitive tasks\\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with recent version of the MikTeX I got no errors and four warnings:

- `LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists  has changed.`
- `Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command deprecated!`
- `Package scrbase Warning: \ifpdftex was redefined`
- `Package scrbase Warning: \ifVTeX was redefined`

Warnings not harm result of compilation. Note, this warnings you obtain also without table proposed solution for your table. MWE gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am adding the packages of multirow etc. I am getting the following error:

Comment: scrpage2.sty
52
Package scrpage2 Warning: usage of obsolete package! Package `scrpage2' is obsolete. You should not longer use package `scrpage2'. You should replace usage of package `scrpage2' by `scrlayer-scrpage' on input line 52.

Comment: @maths, as I said. Error is not in your table code, but as you now discover yourself in use of the obsolete package. Replace it with suggested one. Anyway, code for table in my answer is significantly cleanup from clutter in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much but i am getting again error in '! Undefined control sequence.
l.152 \setcellgapes
                   {3pt}'

Comment: Not with mine MWE (Minimal Working Example, a complete compilable small document). BTW, it has only 34 lines ... Please again, provide your MWE, by which you obtain this error. You may use some package (not present in my MWE) which are not compatible with makecell package.

Comment: @maths - You report that the macro `\setcellgapes` is undefined. Did you maybe fail to load the `makecell` package?

Comment: +1 for the use of `\SIrange`. :-)

Comment: @maths, I add addendum t my answer. In it you will find my suggestion for table also with your document preamble.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you very much for your help. I am getting error: 
header.tex
78
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command deprecated! Usage of `\setheadtopline', `\setheadsepline', `\setfootsepline', and `\setfootbotline' became deprecated with scrlayer-scrpage. You should use KOMA-Script options `headsepline', `headtopline', `footsepline', or `footbotline' with values `<line thickness>:<line length>' to setup the line length and thickness, and `\setkomafont' or `\addtokomafont' to setup the colour on input line 78.

Comment: i am using your new updated version

Comment: @Zarko now its working. It was my failure. Thank you very much for your support

Comment: can anybody help to change the lable from german to English? I renamed the list of tables and figures but the numbering is coming with german language label. For example instead of figure 1 showing Abbildung 1 similarly for table showing tabelle.

Comment: @maths, this is not a forum. If you have new question, ask it as question. As  I remember such question was asked a day or two before ...

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your feedback. Here is the link where i have asked the question. Thank you in advance.       https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/515478/200848